# Reading values from file stream to an array (C)

Tags: c

I have been thinking on this for a while. I was given this assignment that says the following:

There is a text file containing numbers. (MIN, MAX, NUMBER) 
I have to read the contents of the file, then generate a random number between MIN and MAX. If generated number matches the number, then print "Match."

MIN: 7  MAX: 17  NUMBER: 15 
...

I was able to read every number into an array, with this code:

```
int main(void)
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int nums[50] = {0};
    int i = 0;
    FILE * fp;
    /*if(fp == NULL) return 1;*/

    if (fp = fopen("numbers.txt", "r")) {
        while (fscanf(fp, "%d", &nums[i]) != EOF) {
            ++i;
        }
        fclose(fp);
    }

    for (--i; i >= 0; --i)
        printf("num[%d] = %d\n", i, nums[i]);

    return 0;
    }
```

However, I have no idea how to continue. How can I assign the specific values to my random number generator function?

```
int random(int min, int max) {
    return rand()%(max-min+1)+min;
}
```

Comment: `if(fp == NULL) return 1;` ?? You just declared that variable on the previous line with indeterminate content. That line seems pretty worthless (and invokes *undefined behavior* as well).

Comment: Regarding your problem. no array is needed for this task. You need three `int` variables to read the data (`minval, maxval, testval`) from the current line.Then, using `minval` and `maxval`, compute your random number and see if it is the `testval`. If it is, report Match, otherwise, not. You can do it *all* inside one single-scanning for-loop.

Comment: And how can I specifically read the data?
For example: the first number should be min, the second max, the third the test.

Comment: How did you read the *one* value you're reading *now* ? That is *your* code, *right* ?

Comment: I don't understand the question, but yes it's my code. I just don't know the method to assign the numbers to the variables.

Comment: Never mind, I was able to do it with fscanf multiple parameters. Thanks for the input!

Comment: Exactly. There ya go. Knew you'd see it eventually.

Comment: Just keep track of the min and max with something like `min = nums[i] < min ? nums[i] : min` where min is initialize with the first value or 255 if you wan't to do your reading in a single while loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

#### Solution -

You shouldn't use an array since you don't need to store the numbers, you only need to see them once to accomplish your task. We can calculate a random number within our constraints as soon as we read in the numbers. Let's do something like this:

```
int main(void)
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int nums[50] = {0};
    int min = 0, max = 0, match= 0;
    FILE * fp;

    fp = fopen("numbers.txt", "r")

    if(fp == NULL) {
        return 1;
    }

    // Compare the return value of fscanf to 3 to make sure
    // three values were read in from the file during each
    // iteration.
    while (fscanf(fp, "%d %d %d", &min, &max, &match) == 3) {
        if(random(min, max) == match) {
            printf("Match.\n");
        } else {
            //No match!
        }
    }

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}

int random(int min, int max) {
    return rand() % (max - min + 1) + min;
}
```

---

A few other issues with your code could be improved:

- What are you using `srand` for? I don't see it used, so I'll take it out for this bit of code. No need for extra distractions.

  ```
  srand(time(NULL));    // Removing this line.
  ```
- Why have you initialized `nums` to `{0}`? It makes the purpose unclear, and you should just leave it uninitialized.

  ```
  int nums[50] = {0};
  ```

Could also be:

```
int nums[50];
```

- We can clean up the initial part of the file opening, from:

  ```
  /*if(fp == NULL) return 1;*/

  if (fp = fopen("numbers.txt", "r")) {
      ...
  }
  ```

To this:

```
fp = fopen("somenumbers.txt", "r");

if(fp == NULL) {
    //Tell the user an error occured.
    return 1;
}
```